# Header buttons going bigger when you hover over them

Tags: html, css, header

When I hover over the buttons on the header they go bigger, but I want them to stay the same size. How can I do that? There arent that many tutorials on header buttons so I am asking you guys. Roboto font: http://www.dafont.com/roboto.font

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>--snipped--</title>
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
    @font-face{
        font-family: "RobotoLight";
        src: url('font/Roboto-Light.ttf'),
        url('font/Roboto-Light.ttf');
    }

</style>
<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <h1><img src="./pictures/logo.png"></h1>
            <ul>
                <li style="font-family: RobotoLight;"><a href="#">--snipped--</a></li>
                <li style="font-family: RobotoLight;"><a href="#">--snipped--</a></li>
                <li style="font-family: RobotoLight;"><a href="#">--snipped--</a></li>
                <li style="font-family: RobotoLight;"><a href="#">--snipped--</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!--<video autoplay loop id="vid">
            <source src="./videos/background.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video> -->       
    </main> 
</body>
```

styles.css

```
    body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
} 

header div, main { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;   
} 


header { 
    background: #d000c2; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

header h1 { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 17;
    margin:0;
    margin-top: 10;
} 

main { 
    padding: 21; 
} 

header a { 
    margin-top: -14px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white; 
} 

header li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline; 
    right: 14;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 4px
}

header a:hover {
    border-top: 1px cyan;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 0px white;
    border-right: 0px white;
    border-left: 0px white;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #C100B5;
 }

header li a:hover { 
    color: cyan;
} 

header ul { 
    float: right; 
    list-style-type: none; 
} 

#vid{
            position:fixed;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            min-width:100%;
            min-height:100%;
            background-size:cover;
            z-index: -1;
            }

#contact{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 20;
    color: white;
}

main a:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main a:link{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main a:visited{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) { 
    header { 
        text-align: center;
        position: relative; 
    } 
    main { 
        padding: 14 px; 
        } 
    header h1 { 
        float: none; 
        margin: 0; 
    } 
    header ul { 
        float: none; 
        margin: 0;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is common when you don't pay attention to the css you set on the `:hover` state.

The mistake was you had this css on a basic state for your `<li></li>` :

```
header a { 
    margin-top: -14px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;
}
```

And this one for the `hover` state of these `<li></li>` :

```
header a:hover {
    border-top: 1px cyan;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 0px white;
    border-right: 0px white;
    border-left: 0px white;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #C100B5;
 }
```

If you could do some maths to them, you would figure out that in `hover` state, you have an aditionnal `padding : 5px` and `border-top : solid 1px`.

So to fix this, I added on the basic state of you elements a **transparent border-top** and the same **padding** as the one you used on the `hover` state.

You can find the result on this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sot1Lm4c/) link.

Answer (score 0):

It's not font's problem. Remove `padding` of `a tag` when hover and it will no bigger:

```
header a:hover {
    border-top: 1px cyan;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 0px white;
    border-right: 0px white;
    border-left: 0px white;
    padding: 5px; /* remove this padding */
    background-color: #C100B5;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah but then the whole header background of the button area isnt coloured, only the part where the text is http://i.imgur.com/iDBPCjW.png , and I want the border to be at the top of the header too